# PHP: Pulling serialized blob into an array then display

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, blob

I have this code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect(HIDDEN)
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("wow")
or die(mysql_error());
$data = ("SELECT Data FROM wa_guilds") or die(mysql_error());

print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
    Print "<tr>"; 
    Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . "</td> "; 
    Print "<th>Level:</th> <td>".$info['level'] . " </td></tr>"; 
} 
print "</table>";
?>
```

But I'm getting this error:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in blah blah

It's stored as a blob in a row called Data. I'm assuming I have to unserialize it, but I don't really know how.

I'm using this library if it helps any. https://sourceforge.net/p/wowarmoryapi/home/Home/ There's no documentation on how to get the data once it's been cached in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the standard reply : Don't use mysql_... functions. But use mysql**i**_ ... functions or PDO instead. The mysql_... functions are deprecated.

But then to your real answer:

Change

```
$data = ("SELECT Data FROM wa_guilds") or die(mysql_error());
```

into

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT Data FROM wa_guilds") or die(mysql_error());
```

Because in your current code you put a string to $data. But in the code I suggest you run that query with mysql_query() , which will put a response resource in $data.

Comment: Cool I appreciate that. I updated the code and now get this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in DELETED on line 18

Comment: @BrandiEvans Yeah that's because now you are mixing up mysql_... functions with mysqli_... functions. You can't do that. You should either stick to mysql_... functions (deprecated) or use mysqli_... functions. Example: you are using mysqli_query(), but later on using mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: I didn't notice that! ok Thank you for the help <3